# Force JFrog Artifactory to fail when tries to upload already available version

Tags: artifactory

I am looking for options to configure Artifactory in a way that it should fail when someone tries to upload the same release version.

We have Jenkins build setup which uploads the maven artefact and overrides the release version if already exists. Is there anyway in JFrog Artifactory to return an error for already existing Artifactory.

I looked at the JFrog documentation and couldn't find any setting. (I don't if I missed)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a user (like the one you're using to connect Jenkins to Artifctory) or group from overwriting a deployed release or unique snapshot by not granting the Delete permission. Non-unique snapshots can always be overwritten (provided the Deploy permission is granted). More detailed information on managing permissions for certain repos (if that's needed) can be found [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions#ManagingPermissions-PreventingOverwritingDeployments)